# How to get path of VS project subfolder?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a few different types of projects in my web application. Some of those are MyApp.UnitTests, MyApp.UserInterfaceTests, MyApp.Web...

All these have corresponding folders in the `C:\Projects\MyApp` folder. There is a subfolder named `Images` in `MyApp.UserInterfaceTests` - `C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.UserInterfaceTests\Images`, where I store some images I would like to use in my tests.

How can I get path to this folder?

`var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` returns path to assembly, but is there a way to get path of the base project folder inside solution?

Comment: If you absolutely have to use images in your tests it would be better to embedd them as resources in the test DLL so you don't have to wory about environment specific things like file paths.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the folder by

```
filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\"+imagename.extension;
```

But it will better to enclose your resources like images, resx file and so on in class library and access these by dll reference. This approach manages the modularity if changes comes in future.

Other way is if you are using databse, then store base64 form of image in databse. and convert back to its original form while rendering.

Comment: To take the approach of having files within the subfolder you have to right click the file within the Solution Explorer and select Properties - Copy to output directory - Copy if newer.